# Setting the position of an Attachment in a TaskItem does not work in Outlook 2019

Tags: vba, outlook

I try to create a task from a MailItem using VBA in Outlook 2019.
According to the [docu for Attachment.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add):

> Position  Optional    Long:   This parameter applies only to email
> messages using the Rich Text format: it is the position where the
> attachment should be placed within the body text of the message. A
> value of 1 for the Position parameter specifies that the attachment
> should be positioned at the beginning of the message body. A value 'n'
> greater than the number of characters in the body of the email item
> specifies that the attachment should be placed at the end. A value of
> 0 makes the attachment hidden.

However, if I use position 1 (see below), the icon with the link to the original mail will still be at the end of the body instead at beginning. Am I missing something?

```
Sub CreateTask()
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set Msg = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Dim olTask As TaskItem
    Set olTask = olApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
         With olTask
             .Subject = Msg.Subject
             .RTFBody = Msg.RTFBody
             .Attachments.Add Msg, , 1  ' For some reasone position argument not working :(
             '.Save
             .Display
        End With
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Outlook quirk, `.Display` before editing.

Appears it applies in this situation too.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateTask()

    Dim itm As Object
    Dim msg As MailItem
    
    Dim olTask As TaskItem
    
    Set itm = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    
    If itm.Class = olMail Then
    
        Set msg = itm
        Set olTask = CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    
        With olTask

            .subject = msg.subject
            .RTFBody = msg.RTFBody
            
            .Display    ' <--- Earlier rather than later
            
            .Attachments.Add msg, , 1
            
        End With

    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You just saved me a lot of scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MailItem.MarkAsTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.markastask) method which marks a `MailItem` object as a task and assigns a task interval for the object.

Comment: Thx. I tried that approach before, but the MailItems then only show up in the "ToDo List" and cannot be moved into other task folders.